# How can I highlight class methods in Pycharm like Sublime Text 3?

Tags: pycharm, highlight

I just recently got converted to pycharm. Great stuff but I want to have same look and feel of Sublime Text 3. But basically, there are only 2 things I want to highlight:[need to highlight imported class methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foE2U.png)

so that it looks something like this:
[how sublime is displaying this snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff9gA.png)

Many Thanks.